# Putting Hebrew string in a variable using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, unicode, hebrew

I have problem putting Hebrew string in a variable like this:

```
wchar_t* hebrewString = L"א";
```

The value in unicode of **א** is `0x05d0` in hex or 1488 in dec.

The problem is that my memory show different value that totally unconnected 
to the real value of **א**.

If I write:

```
wchar_t hebrewChar = 0x05d0
```

it is obvious that the right value will be in `hebrewChar`, but I want to write regular string.

I thought maybe I did something wrong so I looked up in the generate *ASM* code and even there it was wrong value.

How can I write Hebrew string in a simple way?

---

### Edit 1:

add source code(in comment above the code is the assembly)

```
wchar_t d = 0x05D0;
// DB 0f3H, 05H, 090H, 00H, 00H, 00H
wchar_t *test = L"א";
// mov  eax, 1523               ; 000005f3H
wchar_t test1 = L'א';
// mov  eax, -112               ; ffffff90H
char test2 = 'א';
```

Comment: Wide characters is really not connected to Unicode, it's not even specified what exact size a `wchar_t` is (it may be 16 bits, or 32 bits, or something else). Wide characters is just an *old* way of using international characters, and how they work is up to the compiler really.

Comment: May you please show us your current code/output? I think this question is perfectly valid, as long as you give us enough information to answer it.

Comment: Also, if you do e.g. `wchar_t hebrewChar = L'א';` does it work then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg On Windows `wchar_t` is usually used to represent UTF-16 (or UCS-2 on older systems). It doesn't really matter though, as the compiler obviously translates the string to some other binary value. In order for this to work the source-file (and every string contained) has to be treated as Unicode. 
@amit What IDE are you using? In Visual Studio you can save the file with a certain encoding (File / Save as...). 
I also encourage you to read this: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: I use Visual studio and my file encoding is good (in the source file the letter appear correctly).

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 and `wchar_t* hebrewString = L"א"` gives me the same in-memory value as `wchar_t hebrewChar = 0x05d0`. Using `wchar_t hebrewChar = L'א'` also gives the same result. Therefore I suspect some compiler setting, file encoding, or you are simply looking at the wrong value. Using `wchar_t*` will show as a memory address when debugging (as opposed to `wchar_t`), you have to dereference the pointer to get the real value.

Comment: @amit Also, if you're using visual studio, why are you looking at the disassembly in the first place? I know some people feel comfortable using it but in this case I think it's more confusing than helping. The statement `wchar_t* hebrewString = L"א"` will usually result in a pointer being initialized to some memory address in the executable. Nowhere near this line will you see the actual value contained at that address because the string is compiled into the executable at some other place.

Comment: Provided, source file is encoded in Unicode, `wchar_t d = 0x05D0;` and `wchar_t test1 = L'א';` give same value, and `wchar_t *test = L"א";` make test a pointer pointing to... `0x05D0`. Maybe your source encoding is wrong?

Comment: @amit I just tested various encodings on the file and the symbol was always correctly displayed in Visual Studio but the value nonetheless changed during runtime. So it doesn't really matter if the symbol is shown correctly in the IDE or not, you have to select the correct encoding (Unicode). In Visual Studio open the file, go to File / Advanced Save Options... and choose the correct encoding. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? You mentioned that you verified that the file encoding is good and that the _editor_ can show the file correctly, but, as far as I know, this doesn't guarantee that the _compiler_ is correctly handling that encoding. I suspect that it's a compiler encoding issue and that `L"\x5d0"` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying **L** in front of string or Unicode character, compiler will convert it into an encoding matching the encoding file is saved. Therefore you have to change file encoding via **FILE -> Advance Save Options** and **choose UTF 8 with signature - codepage 65001** for example.

Also bear in mind that Windows Console isn't capable of printing all Unicode characters (you could if you'd have different default language and encoding).

Here is also an example to see if your code is working by saving character into a text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // UCS-2 little endian text file magic number
    char magic_number[] = { 0xFF, 0xFE };    
    wchar_t unicode_char = L'א';
    wchar_t unicode_val = 0x05d0;

    if (unicode_char == unicode_val)
        cout << "Works!" << endl;

    ofstream f("out.txt", ios::out);

    f.write(magic_number, 2);
    f.write((char *)&unicode_char, 2);
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Open the file and check if the value is printed correctly.
Otherwise for storing non ANSI characters in code, I'd strongly recommend using library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) for saving, loading... - in general all operations regarding strings.

Comment: Thanks it was my problam.My file encoding was UTF 8 without signature - codepage 65001.