# Hebrew char translates to "FFFF" in HEX

Tags: c, hex, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a code that translates ASCII char array to a Hex char array:

```
void ASCIIFormatCharArray2HexFormatCharArray(char chrASCII[72], char chrHex[144])
{
  int i,j;
  memset(chrHex, 0, 144); 
  for(i=0, j=0; i<strlen(chrASCII); i++, j+=2)
  {
      sprintf((char*)chrHex + j, "%02X", chrASCII[i]);
  }
  chrHex[j] = '\0';
}
```

When I insert the function the char 'א' - Alef, the equivalent to 'A' in English, the function does this:

```
chrHex = "FFFF"
```

I don't understand how 1 char translates to 2 bytes of Hex ("FFFF") instead of 1 byte(like "u" in ASCII is "75" in Hex) when it's not even an English letter.
would love for an explanation of how the compiler treats 'א' like so.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is happening here, but Aleph is U+05D0 and I don't expect there to be any encoding where it's correctly represented as FF FF. So my guess is that the input to that method already doesn't represent Aleph in a meaningful way, but the problem is at some earlier point. Your usage of `char` implies that you are using either a fix-width 8-bit encoding (such as one of the ISO-8859-* family) or UTF-8. In UTF-8 Aleph would be represented by the bytes `D7 90`. In [ISO-8859-8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-8)  it is `E0`.

Comment: There is a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888349/645128)

Comment: One char is equivalent of 1 byte long so by default you will have a byte representation. Try %x only rather than %02x which gives one byte and I will add space between every byte to represent it better.

Comment: This would have been easy to debug. Viewing the `chrHex` array in each iteration of the loop, with either a debugger or a simple `printf("chrHex = %s.\n", chrHex);` inside the loop, would have revealed what is going on. Submitters should fully examine the execution of code like this before posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

When “א” appears in a string literal, your compiler likely represents it with the bytes D7<sub>16</sub> and 90<sub>16</sub>, although other possibilities are allowed by the C standard.

When these bytes are interpreted as a signed `char`, they have the values −41 and −112. When these are passed as an argument to `sprintf`, they are automatically promoted to `int`. In a 32-bit two’s complement `int`, the bits used to represent −41 and −112 are FFFFFFD7<sub>16</sub> and FFFFFF90<sub>16</sub>.

The behavior of asking `sprintf` to format these with `%02X` is technically not defined by the C standard, because an `unsigned int` should be passed for `X`, rather than an `int`. However, your C implementation likely formats them as “FFFFFFD7” and “FFFFFF90”.

So the first `sprintf` puts “FFFFFFD7” in `chrHex` starting at element 0.

Then the second `sprintf` puts “FFFFFF90” in `chrHex` starting at element 2, partially overwriting the first string. Now `chrHex` contains “FFFFFFFF90”.

Then `chrHex[j] = '\0';` puts a null character an element 4, truncating the string to “FFFF”.

To fix this, change the `sprintf` to expect an `unsigned char` and pass an `unsigned char` value (which will be promoted to `int`, but `sprintf` expects that for `hhX` and works with it):

```
sprintf(chrHex + j, "%02hhX", (unsigned char) chrASCII[i]);
```